# Setting a TaskCompletionSource to Cancel state faults WCF channel

Tags: c#, wcf, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an async WCF operation which I am cancelling on a certain condition (see below). However, I am getting `Faulted` event at client side after this. I also have a FaultHandler configured at Server side but the call does not go to `HandleError` or `ProvideFault`.

Is this the default behavior of `Task` based WCF operation? Shouldn't we get a `OperationCanceledException` at client side?

Sample Code

Operation:

```
Task<MyResult> CalculateResultAsync(SomeParameter parameter);
```

Service Side:

```
Task<MyResult> CalculateResultAsync(SomeParameter parameter)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<MyResult> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MyResult>();

    Task.Run(() => {
        //do something
        //based on some condition cancel tcs
        tcs.SetCanceled();
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of the service does not change the SOAP protocol.

If the service faulted (cancelled), than the client receives a fault.

Besides that, using `Task.Run` on server code is usually a bad practice because it will be trading one thread pool thread for another and back again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My question was specifically about the async operation i.e. why is it causing channel fault if I cancel the returned task. Please note I am still able to make calls to same service with new client (or old client with new channel).

Comment: The task is not returned. It's just part of the server workings. What's returned is a `MyResult`.

Comment: Thanks! I just added a error handler and it is much clear now. The Service does throw TaskCanceledException at service side as well. I was just not sure if this is happening at server side. Thanks again.